# Power BI Advanced Editor - API Pagination Querying Resulting in Many Duplicate Results?

Tags: powerbi, m

Ok I have been stuck on this for a few weeks now. I'm using the Front Email API for a business use case and have created an iterative function to (attempt to) get multiple pages of query results.

A quick overview of the API (endpoint) I'm using for context:

- The "events" endpoint returns a list of records based on the parameters given in the query (like `before`/`after`/`between` certain times, `types` of events, etc.)
- If the query results in more than 100 records, a "next" pagination link is generated for the next page(s) of results. There is no "page=n" parameter in the query URL, you only get the "next page" link from the response of the previous query (which is fairly unique)
- A side note, the initial base_url for the first query, and the base_url of the "next page" link are two different urls (i.e. the initial call is `https://api2.frontapp.com` and the second is `https://companynamehere-inc.api.frontapp.com`), so this is taken into consideration in my querying function.

My environment looks like this:

[image: Query]

[image: QueryFunction]

As you can see, I query the initial URL using the external `Func_Query_Front_API` function, then begin the iteration; While the `next` page link is not `null`, keep feeding the `next` links returned from the previous calls back into the function to get the next page of results. I deconstruct the links given to the function into a `base`, `relative path` and `body`/`params` so that I can use this logic in both Desktop and Online Service (don't ask).

It's difficult to describe the results I get, because sometimes in the preview window, it just clocks and clocks and doesn't return any results with the API not being queried at all (confirmed from Postman and the `rate limit remaining` number in the response headers). When I do get results back, it's a massive list of records (way more than what I'm querying for/expecting to receive) that contains lots of duplicates. It's almost like the initial (or the second) query URL is being looped over and over again, but not the "next" page's links? Like it's somehow stuck in a semi-infinite loop while the "next" link is not null from the initial response only, so it just repeats the same query over and over again re-using the same "next" page link.

Now, unfortunately I cannot provide my bearer token for this API as it's private company info returned by the API, but I'm wondering if the issue is with my syntax in the code that someone can spot and steer me in the right direction. The querying function itself works when invoked on its own, and everything looks like it SHOULD work, but it's just not doing what I think the code is saying it should do.

I understand it's not much to go on, but I'm out of options in trying to debug this thing. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I think what MIGHT help here is a working code written in Python that might help to translate what I'm looking for into Power BI, so I've provided a working code in Python below (again though, the bearer token is not provided, but the syntax should make things a bit clearer). The code closely resembles what I've already made in Power BI as well so hopefully this helps things a bit?

```
import requests
from time import sleep



########################################
# GLOBAL VARIABLES
########################################
_event_types_filter = "assign&q[types]=archive&q[types]=comment&q[types]=inbound&q[types]=outbound&q[types]=forward&q[types]=tag&q[types]=out_reply"
_after = 1667506000
_page_limit = 100
_bearer_token = "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
_init_base_url = "https://api2.frontapp.com"
_relative_path = "events"
_init_body = "limit=" + str(_page_limit) + "&q[after]=" + str(_after) + "&q[types]=" + _event_types_filter
_headers = {'authorization': _bearer_token}
_init_query_url = _init_base_url + "/" + _relative_path + "?" + _init_body



########################################
# FUNCTION - Query the API
########################################
def Func_Query_Front_API(input_url):
    #print(input_url)
    # Deconstruct the url into its separate parts
    splitted_input_url = input_url.split("?")
    input_url_base = splitted_input_url[0].replace("/events", "")
    input_url_body_params = splitted_input_url[1]
    # Query the API
    response = requests.request("GET", 
        input_url_base + "/" + _relative_path + "?" + input_url_body_params, 
        headers=_headers)
    # Get the "next" link from the response
    next = response.json()["_pagination"]["next"]
    # Return the response and the "next" link    
    return response, next
    


########################################
# MAIN PROGRAM START
########################################
# List to add the response data's to
Source = []
# Make the initial request and add the results to the list
init_response, next = Func_Query_Front_API(_init_query_url)
Source.append(init_response)
# While the "next" link(s) are not None, query the current
# "next" link for the next page(s) of the query
while next != None:
    response, next = Func_Query_Front_API(next)
    Source.append(response)
    sleep(1)
print(Source)
print("Done!")
```

Comment: This is a good reference for this type of thing https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: @horseyride It's funny you referenced that article as I literally just read through it yesterday lol the only problem is that, it references an API where you can increment and feed the `offset` value into the query URL each time, which isn't the case with this API. I'm trying to utilize the `next` link that gets generated with each response, but it appears like it's stuck in a `while` loop using the same one `next` link over and over again, which is likely because I'm not using the proper `while` syntax in my code, but I just don't know! Thanks for the ref!